What is the novel which includes people wearing torcs and battling each other after being enclosed in machines which boost their psychic abilities?
The combatants wear torcs and fight each other after entering machines which give them injections to amplify their psychic abilities to some four-figure reading like 2700 or 3400.

This is the Saga of the Pliocene Exiles books by Julian May.
The various characters wear different coloured 'torcs' to amplify their psychic abilities.

A small group journeyed through a time-gate into Europe's prehistoric
past. Yet this supposedly unspoilt sanctuary holds two alien races
locked in combat. In a world where the human-like Tanu have the upper
hand, Elizabeth Orme soon encounters trouble. When they find she
possesses rare mind powers, they want her for their own. She won’t be
used as a pawn in a Tanu versus Firvulag war, but Aiken Drum can’t
wait to get involved.
Aiken discovers the Tanu’s mind-enhancing torcs have given him his own
powerful abilities. And it’s not long before he devises a plan to
challenge the Tanu’s leader – for rule of the Many-Coloured Land
itself. But another faction seeks the slaughter of all humans, and he
stands in their path.

Marc Remillard and his followers have escaped into the past and use machine 'rigs' to amplify their abilities well beyond what the torcs are capable of.

That is the one. Thank you so much!

@RichardTibbitts - You're most welcome
